# Parsing an XML file to retrieve parents according to child element

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I would like to parse an xml file, here's my xml file:

```
<group>
  <name>Services</name>
  <file>
    <name>Path\File1.c</name>
  </file>
  <file>
    <name>Path\File2.c</name>
    <excluded>
      <configuration>Configuration1</configuration>
      <configuration>Configuration2</configuration>
    </excluded>
  </file>
  <file>
    <name>Path\File3.c</name>
    <excluded>
      <configuration>Configuration2</configuration>
      <configuration>Configuration3</configuration>
    </excluded>
  </file>
  <file>
    <name>Path\File4.c</name>
  </file>
</group>
```

This xml file describes the file used within a project. This project has multiple **Configuration** that are named *Configuration1 to Configuration4*. For the example let's assume I have access to those thanks to a list of configuration name.
The xml file list every file used in the project, each *file* is in every *configuration* unless below the file name, the configuration is within the **excluded** tags

What I would like to achieve is a function that:

- Given the xml tree, the configuration name will return a list of all
  file used in this configuration.

I've successfully retrieve every files, here's my code:

```
from lxml import etree

def getSourceFile(sTree, szConfigName):
  #retrieve every file used in the project
  lSource = []
  for data in sTree.xpath('/group'):
      file = data.findall("file")
      for x in file:
        for element in x:
          if(element.tag == "name"):          
              lSource.append(element.text)
  print(lSource)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  sTree = etree.parse("myXmlFile.xml")
  lConfigName = ["Configuration1", "Configuration2", "Configuration3", "Configuration4"]

  for iIdxConfig in range(0, len(lConfigName)):
    getSourceFile(sTree, lConfigName[iIdxConfig])
    print("\n\n")
```

I don't know how I can proceed to check for each file if the current configuration is excluding this file.

Comment: Show your expected result

Comment: Why exists `"Configuration1"` in `lConfigName` **twice**?

Comment: I meant configuration1 to configuration4.

The expected result is:
['File1', 'File3', 'File4'] # For configuration1,         ['File1', 'File4'] # For configuration2,         ['File1', 'File2', 'File4'] # For configuration3,         ['File1', 'File2', 'File3', 'File4'] # For configuration4,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to well understand what you really want to do but maybe this snippet can help you

```
from lxml import etree

def getSourceFile(sTree, szConfigName):
#retrieve every file used in the project
lSource = []
for data in sTree.xpath('/group'):
  file = data.findall("file")
  for x in file:
    myName = ""
    confIsExcluded=False
    for element in x:
      if(element.tag == "name"):
        myName = element.text
      if(element.tag == "excluded"):
        configurations = [config.text for config in element.findall("configuration")]
        if(szConfigName in configurations):
          confIsExcluded=True
    if(not confIsExcluded):
      lSource.append(myName)
print(lSource)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  sTree = etree.parse("myXmlFile.xml")
  lConfigName = ["Configuration1", "Configuration1", "Configuration2", "Configuration3"]

  for iIdxConfig in range(0, len(lConfigName)):
  getSourceFile(sTree, lConfigName[iIdxConfig])
  print("\n\n")
```

Comment: Thanks,
Just note that I edited the list lConfigName where there was a mistake and wrote twice Configuration1 instead of Configuration1 to Configuration4